# Taplytics requirement for the project

Tags: taplytics

I am going to use taplytics for my project.
Wanted to know till which limit is it free.And what else is necessary to use taplytics in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at Taplytics as an Android Engineer.

To answer your first question, the pricing is as follows:

On a free account, you can have 1 project, up to 25 thousand monthly active users, and 2 team members. This also comes with free email support.

---

For your second question:

On **iOS**, not much is necessary at all. Simply install via cocoapods and add one line to get started.

[Here's a link to the iOS starting docs](https://github.com/taplytics/taplytics-ios-sdk/blob/master/START.md)

On **Android** things are a bit more involved.

You will need a networking dependency (volley or retrofit), as well as a socket.io dependency. [You can read more here on the Android SDK docs](https://github.com/taplytics/Taplytics-Android-SDK/blob/master/START.md)